# Statistical analysis for nominal data-advice

Tags: categorical-data

Please, can someone advise me on how I can approach my nominal data and test its significance.

I measured jerking movement as a behavioural effect in a fish exposed to each of Chemical A and Chemical B at different concentrations (or treatments) based on below metrics:

No effect = 1
Low effect = 2
Moderate effect = 3
High effect = 4

I want to now evaluate if there is a significant difference between effect of Chemical A from B. This is how the data look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do a chi-square analysis, but you probably have too few participants - you could try a Fisher's Exact Test, but again statistical tests work best with lots of respondents so you may have to rely on descriptives (crosstabulations) and graphs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a nominal but ordinal data, hence I think kuskal wallis followed by man whitney will be more appropriate